# predict_proba() on a continuos target made binary

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, statistics

I am building a Newtons gravitation equation model. It receives two mass and a radius and outputs what it generates from the formula.

$F = G \frac{m1 · m2}{r^2}$

I want to transform it now to a binary classification model, for that I select a threshold. If the force is above then 1 if below 0.

**The question**

How can I create a predict_proba function given the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Sigmoid function on the Force values(*Scaled to [0-10] based on a max value*)

The Threshold should become 5 after scaling.

```py
def predict_proba(y_pred):

    y_pred = y_pred*10/100000  # scaled to [0-10]
    thresold = 5

    proba = np.exp(y_pred - threshold)/(1 + np.exp(y_pred - threshold))

    return proba
```

`predict_proba(100000), predict_proba(80000), predict_proba(50000), predict_proba(40000), predict_proba(10000), predict_proba(2000)`

> *(0.9933, 0.9525, 0.5, 0.2689, 0.0179, 0.0081)*

Comment: I hope, I have not over-simplified it :-)

Comment: Perfect! Dont know why I did not think of this. :)